# React: Can't figure out how to use fetched API response

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I'm working with a nice [chatbot](https://lucasbassetti.com.br/react-simple-chatbot/) program for React someone wrote, and the thing is, you can actually bind the bot's responses to function calls like this:

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <ChatBot
        steps={[
          {

            ...          
            {
            id: '3',
            message: ({ previousValue, steps }) => {
              this.askAnswer(previousValue)
            },
            end: true,
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
```

Where `message` is the answer of the bot that it calculates based on the `previousValue` and `askAnswer` is a custom function you'd write. I'm using an API that inputs the `previousValue` to a GPT model, and I want to print the response of this API.

However, I just can't wrap my head around how I could pass the response of the API to the message. I'm trying this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { response: " " };
  }
 ...
  askAnswer(question) {
    var jsonData = { "lastConversations": [question] }

    fetch('http://my_ip:80/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)

    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => { this.setState({ response: data["botResponse"] }) });
    return (this.state.response)
  }
```

I've been struggling with this for the past 2-3 hours now.

I've tried a couple of combinations, and nothing seems to work:

- If I do as seen above, it seems like `this.state.response` just won't get
  updated (logging `data["botResponse"]` shows there is a correct
  reply, so the API part works and I get the correct response).
- If I try async-await for `askAnswer` and the `fetch` call, then I can
  only return a `Promise`, which is then incompatible as input for the
  ChatBot `message`.
- If I do not `await` for the `fetch` to complete, then
  `this.state.response` just stays the default `" "`.
- If I `return` the correct `data["botResponse"]` from within the second `.then` after the fetch, nothing happens.

How am I supposed to get the API result JSON's `data["botResponse"]` text field out of the `fetch` scope so that I can pass it to `message` as a text? Or, how can I get a non-Promise string return after an await (AFAIK this is not possible)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your last 2 line

```
.then(data => { this.setState({ response: data["botResponse"] }) });
return (this.state.response)
```

You are updating the state and trying to read and return the value in the same function which I think will never work due to async behaviour of state. (this is why your **this.state.response** in the return statement is the previous value, not the updated state value).

I'm not sure but you can write a callback on this.setState and return from there, the callback will read the updated state value and you can return the new state.

Comment: But how do I achieve getting a function that returns a string? If I do a callback, I lose control over the function call. I need the askAnswer to return a string directly, not a promise... That's what's been baffling me. I know about callbacks. I wouldn't mind having a couple of functions calling each other, but I need to create an API call and return a non-promise string within the same function or in a way that I can make sure message gets a string.

Comment: I meant rewritiing your .then statement as -  .then(data => { this.setState({ response: data["botResponse"] }, ()=>{return (this.state.response)}) });

Comment: Nothing happens when you return data["botResponse"] is because the component doesn't re-render and is not able to update with the new value.

Comment: If I use your return, nothing happens, it's the wrong scope. I understand why it doesn't work, I'd like to know how it can.

Comment: A doubt, you are calling the function (askAnswer} from render and that function is updating the state, isn't your whole component re-rendering infinite?

Comment: I don't think the componenet is re-rendering at all, I think that's the issue.

Comment: But according to principles, a state change would make the whole component re-render. I tried copying your code, message : this.askAnswer() was not calling the askAnswer function. Maybe this is the case component is not rerendering infinite. You can verify this.